# Complex charts in Google Charts

Tags: graph, charts

For a web application I'm working on, I need some pretty powerful graphing capabilities. I'm looking at using Google Charts for my needs.

I'm wondering if Google Charts is capable of producing a graph to the complexity of the one in the image below:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/843/graphexample.png/

If not, are there any other graphing APIs I can use to create a chart to that complexity? Preferably in PHP.

EDIT: Doesn't only have to be Google Charts. I'm looking for something that can handle the above. Commercial solutions are fine as long as the cost is reasonable.

Comment: Have you read [Google's chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/) developer information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using pChart to achieve what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [jqChart Plugin for jQuery](http://www.jqchart.com/) for this. You can easily combine column, scatter and line series with specifying custom markers.

Take a look at the [samples](http://www.jqchart.com/samples/Combinational/SplineScatter).

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried Fusion Charts?

It's the best charting library I've seen.  I've used them for web projects and iOS projects as well since they have now JS versions of everything.

Pretty complex graphics, wide range of charts, and even real-time widgets.

They're not free but totally worth it to consider.  I've done everything related to pilots and demo projects with the trial version.

Check them out at http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/

Answer (score 1):

In the past i used Fusion charts, and i like so much. It was a good charts library, but you probably would have to pay in order use without restrictions. Well, google charts its nice library too, but with less graphic classes. But i think that combo graphic fits your interests.

Get more information with the link below:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom plugin for both Charts and Tables.
Hope its useful to you.
**Feel free to use my custom Google Charts plugin which creates both chart and** table. https://github.com/cosmoarunn/gapiExt