# Processing Javascript on the server

Tags: javascript, server-side

I'm looking to use this chart generation library: http://www.jqchart.com/

Ideally, I would prefer to use a PHP charting library for the current project I'm working, but, by the looks of it, this is the only library I've found that can handle what I need to do (given a somewhat unconventional requirement for the charts).

The issue is that I need to get the generated graphs as images (at the moment each graph seems to be a combination of images) to the server so that I can generate some PDF documents, etc.

I'm thinking of attempting to create an image using JS, pushing this back to the server and then generating the PDF although this pretty nasty and will probably cause issues between different versions of the browser.

So now what I'm looking for is a solution that will allow me to generate the graphs and turn them into images on the backend.

Any ideas?

EDIT: For the requirement that led me to rule out a number of other charting libraries, see here: [Complex charts in Google Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306606/complex-charts-in-google-charts)

That really isn't all that relevant to the question of processing Javascript on the server, though.

Comment: It would help if you let us know what your "unconventional requirement for the charts" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render a javascript graph on the server using  [phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/). [Here is an example.](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Rendering)

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I need. Will look at evaluating tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your requirements are, but I'd check out Google Chart Tools: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/. It's really simple to use. All the data is in the image URL get request, so you can generate charts using client-side JavaScript too.